# Java background moving

Tags: java

well i think there are 2 ways to make  something like a game when the player is moving.
1st the background can be something like a gif that  make people think that it is moving.

2nd the background can be a big image and the player really move in there and the image keeps moving to right or left ( like mario bros).

i'm making something like a " `space game` " where the player should shoot , but now i'm not sure how to make the background move i would like to get some help about it thanks  .

i'm thinking on use something like with the threads like this.

```
public void run() {
   while (true) {
      this.mydrawfunction();
   }
}
```

and yeah i  used `paintComponent` to make a background but it isn't moving

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your painting method, you need an offset. For example, to move background in X axis, it would be something like this.

```
public class Game {
    int offset_x = 0;

    public void onEvent() {
        if (move_to_left) {
            offset_x++;
        }
        else if (move_to_right) {
            offset_x--;
        }
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.draw(backgroundImage, offset_x, y);
    }
}
```

Regards